# eclipselink @orderby Comparable

Tags: java, jpa, sql-order-by, eclipselink

let be the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    long id;

    @ManyToOne
    Family fam;

    @ManyToOne
    Job job;
 }

@Entity
class Family{
    @Id
    long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="fam")
    @OrderBy("job")
    List<Person> p;
}


@Entity
class Job implements Comparable<Job>{
    @Id
    long id;

    String descr;

    public int compareTo(Job o) {
        return descr.compareTo(o.descr);
    }
}
```

the problem i'm facing comes from the @orderby annotation which, far from what i was expecting, seems to be not supporting the comparable entities.

I'm using the eclipselink 2.3 and wondering if there's any other facility that deals with this problem.

Best Regards
George

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@OrderBy` is used to sort the entities using an "order by" clause in the generated SQL queries. So, of course, it doesn't the compareTo method. If you want to sort using Java, then just return a sorted list in the getter `getPersons()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think i'll use a TreeSet.

Comment: You won't be able to use a TreeSet, because you need to use interfaces and not concrete types. EclipseLink might support SortedSet, but I would check.

Comment: Are you sure of this? I tried using the SotedSet but it didn't work, i get a class instantiation exception. However there were no problem when i used the TreeSet, it just requires specifying the fetch type (i tried eager).

Comment: Good answer. @George, for JPA type of this persistent attribute have to be Set (and not any subinterface or implementation), but you can have separate method that returns attribute as ordered. As simple as it gets: return new TreeSet(collectionOfPersons, someComparatorThatComparesPersons). Or you can have ordered view to the persistent attribute if you also want to modify them via ordered collection.

Comment: actually i take back what i said on my previous comment, it worked for me in a non jpa project, i don't understand how but it did , however when i tried to re-do it in a jpa project i got errors...  i'm going to use a List, and in the getter i'll sort it (Collections.sort(persons)) before return. Thanks for the help